# Javascript checks if any text was entered on form submit is just not working

Tags: javascript

I know this is a very basic JS question and I apologize. I am very new to this. I must be making a mistake somewhere. Here is what I am working with:

HTML Form

```
<div class='nameinput'>Please enter your name:</div>
<input id='name1' placeholder='Name...' type='text'>
<input type='submit' value='Connect' class="submitForm">
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
  function store() {
    name = $("input#name1").val();
  }

  function init() {
    $('.submitForm').on('click', function(){

  if (name === '') {
  alert("Please Enter Name");
  } 

  else  
      store();
      $(".login_page").animate({
        'opacity': '0' });
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. The `name = $("input#name1").val();` works fine but I can't seem to get the if to work right. Could someone kindly explain my issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `name` is `undefined` in the scope. You need to get it when the button is clicked. Change your code to something like this:

```
function init() {
  $('.submitForm').on('click', function() {
    var name = $("#name1").val();

    if (name === '') {
      alert("Please Enter Name");
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

Also, you don't need the function `store` if you're using it only to initialize the variable `name`. Additionally, the selector `input#name1` can be simplified to `#name1` as all elements in the page should have unique IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I am still new and learning JavaScript in many ways, so don't worry.

First, you should always try to debug the problem as much as possible. One easy way to do that is simply putting in test `console.log()` statements printing out relevant values so you 1) know what is firing and when, and 2) what values they are working with. That'll get you out of a lot of problems like this.

Second, your if statement (`if (name === '') {`) I believe is the problem. You should look at this and ask yourself why isn't it working? Is your logical comparison written wrong? are you comparing the right things? What values are you comparing?

Your problem is: where is `name` defined? You use it in `store()`, but it pops up for the first time in `init` in that `if` statement. It's not defined prior to that.

So the first time it fires, that can't be true, and it goes to the `else` clause and *then* `store()` fires.

In this case, you've lost track of scope; where your variables are being defined.

The easiest solution is to add another statement to extract the value of the input you are trying to check and making sure it's not null/empty. For that matter, I don't think you need `store()` at all, unless you had some specific purpose for it.

Comment: Yes, I am very new to JS. This console.log() is extremely helpful, wish I was aware of it earlier. I got frustrated and must have been lost out of order, that makes sense. I will try your suggestions and see what I can come up with. Much appreciated.